# iOS UItableviewcell is not updating when row deleted from the backend URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a problem on my objective-C iOS App.

I have a UItableview with multiple row defined with data loaded from my backend URL

This table view is a Job Table. let say that on my backend I have 3 row for this job table (photographer, architect and teacher). If i add a new job (baker), it is correctly download on the tableview when I restart my App (so 4 row on the App).

Now when I am deleting a job on my backend, the job is not deleted from the table on my iPhone. It's causing me trouble as users selecting the deleted job row are facing a crash or an error ... to remove it I have to delete the App and reload it (which is a real mess)

What would you recommend me ?

Many many thanks for your help,

Best, David

```js
//  JobsVC.m

#import "JobsVC.h"
#import "DataProvider.h"
#import "JobsTableViewCell.h"
#import "DBJobs.h"
#import "DBLinkUserJob.h"
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>

@interface JobsVC ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *jobsTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *okButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *selectJobsView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *selectJobsTitleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *selectJobsDetailsLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *jobsDataSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedJobs;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *jobsArray;

@end

@implementation JobsVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.selectedJobs = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.jobsDataSource = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    self.jobsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.verifiedHyperjobs = [NSMutableArray new];
    
    [self initialSetup];
    [self loadJobs];
    
    
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.jobsTableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //Editing header view according to selection mode
    if (self.jobsMode == Jobs_Mode_Lb || self.jobsMode == Jobs_Mode_Ad) {
        
        [self.selectJobsView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.selectJobsView.frame.origin.x, self.selectJobsView.frame.origin.x, self.selectJobsView.frame.size.width, 60.0)];
        
        
        [self.selectJobsTitleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(self.selectJobsTitleLabel.frame.origin.x, 19.0, self.selectJobsTitleLabel.frame.size.width, 0.0)];
        
        
        [self.selectJobsDetailsLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(self.selectJobsDetailsLabel.frame.origin.x, 19.0, self.selectJobsDetailsLabel.frame.size.width, 36.0)];
        
        [self.selectJobsTitleLabel setText:@""];
        [self.selectJobsDetailsLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"jobs_select_ad_lb_jobs", nil)];
        [self.selectJobsDetailsLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN Alternate" size:18]];
        [self.selectJobsDetailsLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:0.6];
    }
    else{
        
        [self.selectJobsView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.selectJobsView.frame.origin.x, self.selectJobsView.frame.origin.x, self.selectJobsView.frame.size.width, 180.0)];
        
        [self.selectJobsTitleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(self.selectJobsTitleLabel.frame.origin.x, 19.0, self.selectJobsTitleLabel.frame.size.width, 36.0)];
        
        [self.selectJobsDetailsLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(self.selectJobsDetailsLabel.frame.origin.x, 63.0, self.selectJobsDetailsLabel.frame.size.width, 117.0)];
        
        [self.selectJobsTitleLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"jobs_select_title", nil)];
        [self.selectJobsTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AWConquerorDidot-Light" size:24]];
        [self.selectJobsTitleLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:0.6];
        [self.selectJobsDetailsLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"jobs_select_details", nil)];
        [self.selectJobsDetailsLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN Alternate" size:18]];
        [self.selectJobsDetailsLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:0.6];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma  mark - Helpers
- (void)initialSetup {
    [self setupNavigationBar:YES];
    if (self.jobsMode == Jobs_Mode_Lb || self.jobsMode == Jobs_Mode_Ad || ![LogicManager sharedInstance].currentUserID) {
        [self.navigationItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"jobs_ttl", nil)];
    } else {
        DBUsers *userDB = [DBUsers MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"userID" withValue:[LogicManager sharedInstance].currentUserID];
        [self.navigationItem setTitle:userDB.login];
    }
    
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar
     setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
                              NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"AWConquerorDidot-Light" size:24]}];
    
    
    [self.okButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"button_ok", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.okButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN Alternate" size:16]];
}

#pragma  mark - Logic
- (void)loadJobs {
    [self.jobsDataSource removeAllObjects];
    [self.jobsArray removeAllObjects];
    if (!self.selectedJobs.count) {
        if (self.jobsMode == Jobs_Mode_Lb) {
            self.selectedJobs = [DataProvider sharedInstance].lbJobsArray;
        } else if (self.jobsMode == Jobs_Mode_Ad) {
            self.selectedJobs = [DataProvider sharedInstance].adJobsArray;
        } else {
            self.selectedJobs = [DataProvider sharedInstance].userJobsArray;
        }
    }
    
//    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(isM == NO)"];
//    NSMutableArray *sources = [[DBJobs MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
//    NSMutableArray *sources = [[DBJobs MR_findAll] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray* sources = [[[[DBJobs MR_findAll] mutableCopy] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        if([[LogicManager sharedInstance].deviceLanguage containsString:@"fr"]){
            return [NSLocalizedString([(DBJobs*)a name_fr],nil) caseInsensitiveCompare:NSLocalizedString([(DBJobs*)b name_fr],nil)];
        }
        else{
            return [NSLocalizedString([(DBJobs*)a name],nil) caseInsensitiveCompare:NSLocalizedString([(DBJobs*)b name],nil)];
        }
    }] mutableCopy];
    
    
    for (DBJobs *jobDB in sources) {
        NSString *jobName = [[LogicManager sharedInstance].deviceLanguage containsString:@"fr"] ? jobDB.name_fr : jobDB.name;
        NSString *jobIndex = [[jobName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
        if (![[[self.jobsDataSource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] containsObject:jobIndex]) {
            NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
            [mutableArray addObject:jobDB];
            [self.jobsDataSource setValue:mutableArray forKey:jobIndex];
        } else {
            NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [self.jobsDataSource objectForKey:jobIndex];
            if (![mutableArray containsObject:jobDB]) {
                [mutableArray addObject:jobDB];
                [self.jobsDataSource setValue:mutableArray forKey:jobIndex];
            }
        }
        [self.jobsArray addObject:jobDB];
    }
    sortedKeys = [[self.jobsDataSource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}

- (void)refreshData {
    [[ServiceManager sharedInstance] loadJobsWithCompletion:^(NSArray *responce, NSString *errorMessage) {
        if ([self.refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        }
        if (errorMessage) {
            [[LogicManager sharedInstance] showAlertWithTitleKey:@"api_msg_error" AndMessage:errorMessage];
        } else {
            [self loadJobs];
        }
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Actions
- (IBAction)okButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    if(self.selectedJobs.count == 0){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"jobs_select_title", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"jobs_no_job_msg", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else{
        if (self.jobsMode != Jobs_Mode_Lb && self.jobsMode != Jobs_Mode_Ad) {
            
            BOOL hasSelectedHyperJob = FALSE;
            NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
            NSMutableArray *tempHyperArray = [NSMutableArray new];
            
            //Get selected hyperjobs for request
            for(NSString *jobID in self.selectedJobs){
                DBJobs *jobDB = [DBJobs MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"jobID" withValue:jobID];
                if([jobDB.isM boolValue]){
                    hasSelectedHyperJob = TRUE;
                    [tempArray addObject:jobID];
                }
            }
            
            //Check for verified hyperjobs in selected hyperjobs and remove them from request
            for(NSString *jobID in tempArray){
                for(NSString* selectedJobID in self.verifiedHyperjobs){
                    if([selectedJobID isEqualToString:jobID]){
                        [tempArray removeObject:jobID];
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //Check for removed hyperjobs
            for(NSString *jobID in self.verifiedHyperjobs){
                BOOL isSelected = FALSE;
                for(NSString* selectedJobID in self.selectedJobs){
                    if([selectedJobID isEqualToString:jobID]){
                        isSelected = TRUE;
                    }
                }
                if(isSelected == FALSE){
                    [tempHyperArray addObject:jobID];
                }
            }
            
            //Remove deleted hyperjob
            for (NSString *jobID in tempHyperArray){
                [self.verifiedHyperjobs removeObject:jobID];
            }
            
            
            MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
            hud.color  = [UIColor whiteColor];
            hud.labelColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            hud.detailsLabelColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
            hud.customView = [LogicManager sharedInstance].HudActivity;
            hud.dimBackground = YES;
            //Request hyperjob
            BOOL shouldReturn = FALSE;
            for (NSString *jobID in tempArray){
                [self.selectedJobs removeObject:jobID];
                if([self.selectedJobs count] == 0){
                    //adding "Awaiting Status Verification" job
                    [self.selectedJobs addObject:@"57"];
                }
                
                shouldReturn = TRUE;
                
                NSString *lang = @"en";
                if([[LogicManager sharedInstance].deviceLanguage containsString:@"fr"]){
                    lang = @"fr";
                }
                
                [[ServiceManager sharedInstance] requestHyperjob:jobID forEmail:self.userEmail userID:self.userID language:lang lastName:self.userLastName andFirstName:self.userFirstName completion:^(id responce, NSString *errorMessage) {
                    if (!errorMessage && [responce[@"error"] intValue] == 0) {
                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"hint_hyperjobs", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"hint_hyperjobs_txt", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alert show];

                        //show success
                    } else {
                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"hint_hyperjobs", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"api_msg_error", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alert show];

                    }
                }];
            }
            
            if(shouldReturn == TRUE){
                return;
            }

        }
        
        NSLog(@" selected jobs : %@", self.selectedJobs);
        
        
        if (self.jobsMode == Jobs_Mode_Lb) {
            [DataProvider sharedInstance].lbJobsArray = self.selectedJobs;
        } else if (self.jobsMode == Jobs_Mode_Ad) {
            [DataProvider sharedInstance].adJobsArray = self.selectedJobs;
        } else {
            [DataProvider sharedInstance].userJobsArray = self.selectedJobs;
        }
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}


#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate & DataSource1
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    JobsTableViewCell*cell = (JobsTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//    NSString *sectionTitle = [[[self.jobsDataSource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
//    NSMutableArray *array = [self.jobsDataSource objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    DBJobs *jobDB = [self.jobsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.jobNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN Alternate Bold" size:16]];
    
    [cell.jobNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(142.0/255.0) green:(142.0/255.0) blue:(142.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
    
    if ([self.selectedJobs containsObject:jobDB.jobID]) {
        
        if([jobDB.isM boolValue]){
            [cell.jobNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(210.0/255.0) green:(196.0/255.0) blue:(169.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
        }
        
        [self.selectedJobs removeObject:jobDB.jobID];
    } else {
        [self.selectedJobs addObject:jobDB.jobID];
        [cell.jobNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN Alternate" size:20]];
        
        if([jobDB.isM boolValue]){
            [cell.jobNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(168.0/255.0) green:(148.0/255.0) blue:(109.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
        }
        else{
            [cell.jobNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"selected jobs : %@", self.selectedJobs);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//    return [[self.jobsDataSource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)].count;
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 40;
}

//- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//    return [[self.jobsDataSource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
//}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//    NSString *sectionTitle = [[[self.jobsDataSource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
//    NSArray *array = [self.jobsDataSource objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [self.jobsArray count];
}

//- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
//    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:index];
//    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
//    return index;
//}
//
//- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//    return [[[self.jobsDataSource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
//}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    JobsTableViewCell*cell = (JobsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JobsTableViewCell"];
    //NSString *sectionTitle = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
//    NSString *sectionTitle = [[[self.jobsDataSource allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
//    NSMutableArray *array = [self.jobsDataSource objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    DBJobs *jobDB = [self.jobsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.width = self.view.width;
    cell.jobNameLabel.text = [[LogicManager sharedInstance].deviceLanguage containsString:@"fr"] ? jobDB.name_fr : jobDB.name;
    [cell.jobNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN Alternate Bold" size:16]];
    
    [cell.jobNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(142.0/255.0) green:(142.0/255.0) blue:(142.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    if ([self.selectedJobs containsObject:jobDB.jobID]) {
        [cell.jobNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN Alternate" size:20]];
        
        if([jobDB.isM boolValue]){
            [cell.jobNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(168.0/255.0) green:(148.0/255.0) blue:(109.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
            if(self.jobsMode != Jobs_Mode_Ad && self.jobsMode != Jobs_Mode_Lb){
                [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
            }
        }
        else{
            [cell.jobNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }
        
        //        [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    } else {
        //        [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        
        if([jobDB.isM boolValue]){
            [cell.jobNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(210.0/255.0) green:(196.0/255.0) blue:(169.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UIAlertView Delegate Methods
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    [self okButtonPressed:0];
}


@end
```

```js
//  ServiceManager.m

#import "ServiceManager.h"

#import "LogicManager.h"
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>
#import "DataProvider.h"
#import "DBJobs.h"
#import "Constants.h"


static NSString * const ApiJobsURLString = @"/api/v1/jobs/";


#pragma mark - JOBS
- (void)loadJobsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *responce,NSString * error))completion {
    if (!self.isConnected) {
        completion(nil, NSLocalizedString(@"msg_internet",nil));
        return;
    }
    [self GET:ApiJobsURLString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        if (completion) {
            if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                NSArray *arrayResponce = [responseObject objectForKey:@"jobs"];
                for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayResponce) {
                    [self saveJob:dict];
                }
            }
            
            completion(responseObject, nil);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSData *errorData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey];
        if (!errorData) {
            (error.code == -1005 || error.code == -1009) ? completion(nil, NSLocalizedString(@"msg_internet",nil)) : completion(nil, NSLocalizedString(error.description,nil));
            return;
        }
        NSDictionary *serializedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: errorData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        NSString *errorMessage = [serializedData objectForKey:@"message"];
        if (completion) {
            completion(nil, NSLocalizedString(errorMessage,nil));
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling reloadData after deleting row ?

Comment: Hi @Pushkraj Thanks for your respond. I tried a lot regarding this problem. I'm facing an issue on my code, i don't know which part I should changed anymore ...